# How to delete a table row in Asp.Net MVC on <a></a> html tags click without returning a view using Ajax and sweetAlert popup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am building a Web Application and I am finding difficulties using Ajax to delete table rows without returning a view but by just showing a sweetalert popup. I have managed to make functional the swal popup and this popup has 2 buttons OK and Cancel. After the swal comes the function which should include Ajax code inside the if block in case OK has been clicked. I click on the icon inside the 'a' html tag but it doesn't work. How to solve this?

Comment: can you post snippet or gist?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/sweet-alert-with-mvc/